# Displaying text on Customer Display

Tags: c#, point-of-sale

We've been programming a POS application for our client using PioneerPOS's S-Line. We have a few problems working with the customer display.

1- We are able to send text to customer display but this text is displayed at random position. We want to display text at a particular column & row index.

2- The customer display always displays '!#2' when we clear the screen.

3- When we display our text it  appends to '!#1' . For example sending 'Hello' would appear as  '!#1Hello'.

This is worth mentioning that we are working on a .net application(C#) and using POS.net to access the device.

In case it helps here is my code for doing this.

```
    private void Display(bool blink)
    {
        LineDisplay lineDisplay;
        PosExplorer explorer;
        try
        {

            explorer = new PosExplorer(this);
            DeviceCollection devColl = explorer.GetDevices(DeviceType.LineDisplay);
            if (devColl == null || devColl.Count <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Device not found");
                return;
            }

            lineDisplay = (LineDisplay)explorer.CreateInstance(devColl[0]);
            lineDisplay.Open();

            lineDisplay.Claim(1000);

            lineDisplay.DeviceEnabled = true;

            if (blink)
                lineDisplay.DisplayText("Hello World..!", DisplayTextMode.Blink);
            else
                lineDisplay.DisplayText("Hello World.!", DisplayTextMode.Normal);

            lineDisplay.Release();
            lineDisplay.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you test the customer display using the provided test app(http://www.pioneerpos.com/support.php) does it work as expected ?

Comment: @AdrianFaciu - They say it should display a scrolling text after running the configurator. In my case the scrolling text appears but even that text ends with !#2. The text says 'Pioneer POS Line dispaly!#2 ; Release 1.10.00!#2

Comment: It might be something related to the configuration or drivers. I would suggest to contact pioneerpos support, they could probably help you more.

Answer (score 0):

To display at particular coordinates, try:

```
Linedisplay.displaytextat(RowNum, ColPos, "Text To Display");
```

Remember both row and column start at 0.